# Automatically Loading all Reposts on Soundcloud Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, soundcloud

Hi I'm trying to run a script to capture information from various Soundcloud pages, but these kinds of things are updated with some kind of AJAX call I believe when you scroll down the page. Is there a good way to get these to load without manually scrolling down? I tried to go through the JS pages for the page but couldn't find the correct functions.

Comment: A *good* way?  Not really.  But you could try to reverse-engineer their AJAX calls and send the requests yourself.

Comment: Why not use SoundCloud's API?